# Polynomials of degree $n$ as a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> Let $P$ be the set of polynomials $p: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}, x \mapsto a_n x^n + \cdots + a_1x + a_0$ equipped with addition and scalar multiplication. Show that $P$ is a vector space.

Since $P$ is equipped with scalar multiplication I have that $$cp = ca_n x^n + \cdots + ca_1x + ca_0$$ so it is closed under multiplication.

Now let $p = a_n x^n + \cdots + a_1x + a_0$ and $q = b_n x^n + \cdots + b_1x + b_0$ from which one gets that $$p+q = (a_n+b_n)x^n+(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1})x^{n-1} + \dots + a_0+b_0$$

so its closed under addition. I'm not really sure how to proceed from here, how can I show that this is a vector space?

Comment: There are axioms of a vector space that you have to check. They are all very easy.

Answer (score 2):

$P$ is the set of all polynomials of degree **at most** $n$. It is thus a subset of the set of all polynomials that forms a vector space equipped with addition and scalar multiplication. In order to show that $P$ is a vector space, it suffices to prove it is a subspace of the vector space of all polynomials so you only need to check for closure under addition and scalar multiplication, as you have done.